# Verify Windows session with lDAP server

Tags: node.js, ldap, node-sspi

I want to ask how to verify a windows session with the ldap server.
In fact, I'm using node-sspi (nodeJS package) to get the windows session:

```
{
  "username": "DOMAIN\\Username",
  "authenticationType": "NTLM",
  "groups": [
    "Domain Users",
    "Administrators",
    "Power Users"
  ],
  "sid": "S-1-5-21-3623811015-3361044348-30300820-1013",
  "domain": "DOMAIN",
  "accessToken": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJET01BSlNPTiV1OSIsIm5iZiI6MTUxNjIzOTczNCwiZXhwIjoxNTE2MjQwMjM0fQ.c9s6XoZfDxL3eaH20QZm7lV3iSBOFp97Y0-U0T90uGw"
}
```

How can I verify this with the ldap Server? How to verify that the accessToken is valid?